Flutter JSON Error - The getter body isn't defined for the type StreamedResponse
I am trying to retrieve values returned after an API call but I am getting this error message:
The getter 'body' isn't defined for the type 'StreamedResponse'.
Try importing the library that defines 'body', correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'body'.
Here is my code:
loginUser() async{
  try{
    final uri = Uri.parse(API.loginURL);
    var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

    //Send Input field data
    request.fields['email'] = emailController.text;
    request.fields['password'] = passwordController.text;

    var response = await request.send();

    if(response.statusCode == 200){
      var resBody = jsonDecode(response.body);
      bool success_flag = resBody['success'];
      print("Login successful!");
    }else{
      print("Login failed!");
    }
  }
  catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
  }
}

It seems the response doesn't have a body

You need to read the response's stream and convert it to a String before you attempt to decode it:
if( response.statusCode == 200) {
   var responseData = await http.Response.fromStream(response);
   var resBody = jsonDecode(responseData.body);
   bool success_flag = resBody['success'];
   print("Login successful: $success_flag");
} else {
   ...

PS: it's not recommended to mix coding styles and you have camelCase with snake_case together. Stick to one (if unsure, simply go with the flow and use one most popular on given ecosystem/platform you use).

You mean success_flag should be successFlag? Also which is the popular style for naming variables? I am new to Flutter/Dart?

about "successFlag" - yes. For consistency keep one style. For Dart style please see https://dartwiki.com/wiki/Dart_Style_Guide/Naming_Conventions - just use what majority does (which probably be camelCase)

Use code like below with try and catch blocks
final uri = Uri.parse(API.loginURL);
var request = http.MultipartRequest('POST', uri);

request.fields['email'] = emailController.text;
request.fields['password'] = passwordController.text;

var response = await request.send();

var streamedResponse = await http.Response.fromStream(response);

if (streamedResponse.statusCode == 200) {
  var resBody = jsonDecode(streamedResponse.body);
  bool successFlag = resBody['success'];
  if (successFlag) {
    print("Login successful!");
  } else {
    print("Login failed: ${resBody['message']}");
  }
} else {
  print("Login failed status code: ${streamedResponse.statusCode}");
}

